# wmic command to append the results

Tags: command, append, wmic

My scenario:

I have a wmic command used to collect software details.

wmic product get description,name,version /format:csv > /softwarelist.csv

This works fine.

But i need the results to be appended on the same output file.ie,If i run the script on another system,it has to write the output to the same softwarelist.csv file.

I have tried using the APPEND command,but it gives access denied error.

wmic /APPEND:"\softwarelist.csv" product get description,name,version /format:csv

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Read **[Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)**:

> ```
> command > filename        Redirect command output to a file
> command >> filename       APPEND into a file
> ```

You could use `>>`, see next syntax:

```
wmic product get description,name,version /format:csv >>/softwarelist.csv
```

Read **wmic /APPEND /?**:

> ```
> APPEND - Specifies the mode for output redirection.
> USAGE:
>
> /APPEND:<outputspec>
> NOTE: <outputspec> ::= (STDOUT | CLIPBOARD | <filename>)
>       STDOUT     - Output will be redirected to the STDOUT.
>       CLIPBOARD  - Output will be copied on to CLIPBOARD.
>       <filename> - Output will be appended to the specified file.
>
> NOTE: Enclose the switch value in  double quotes, if the value contains special 
>       characters like '-' or '/'.
> ```

`wmic /APPEND`  should work as well although it appears that `<filename>` does not accept relative paths, see next example. Use either bare file name or fully qualified file path:

```
==> dir /B "\softwarelist.csv"
File Not Found

==> >NUL wmic /APPEND:"\softwarelist.csv" product get description,name,version /format:csv
Invalid file name.

==> >NUL wmic /APPEND:"D:\softwarelist.csv" product get description,name,version /format:csv

==> dir "\softwarelist.csv" | findstr "softwarelist.csv$"
27.08.2016  19:47            48 644 softwarelist.csv
```

Note that `dir /B "\softwarelist.csv"` ensures that the later `wmic /APPEND` in above code snippet works.

**Moreover**, root directory of system drive is protected (since *Vista* times?), see **Access is denied** message:

```
==> pushd c:

==> wmic product get description,name,version /format:csv >/softwarelist.csv
Access is denied.
```